# Given two -exec arguments to find, is there any elegant way to pass state or variables?

Tags: bash, find

I was hoping for:

```
find . [whatever] -exec VAR="$(another command)" \;  -exec [use $VAR here] \;
```

but this predictably falls apart because the two -exec are different processes.

Any *elegant* way to pass state from a computation to another that is not `bash -c "mess of escaped characters here" "{}"`? I don't mind if it's a bash or GNU find extension.

BTW, i *can* use the command into the cmd with $(secondary cmd) however, variable expansion not being lazy is screwing me over. If one tries:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.gdi" -execdir echo $( basename "{}" .gdi )  \;
```

i get a nice

```
++ basename '{}' .gdi
+ find . -type f -iname '*.gdi' -execdir echo '{}' ';'
./game.gdi
```

That is variable expansion happens before the find -exec subprocess and reduces the basename call to a ident function joke. I can't find a way to delay this that it's not yet another subprocess with a bash call.

Comment: There isn't; package your code in a file and invoke that as a shell script. `find . [whatever] -exec bash myscript {} \;`. `-exec` is meant to call a *single* command with arguments, not arbitrary shell code.